# Magento 2 How to send Tax Amount To Braintree and Paypal

Tags: magento2, tax, paypal, braintree

I need to be able to view the tax charged when I go into my paypal and braintree accounts.  Magento is not sending this information to them.  We are tring using 2.2.5 and 2.3.1 Enterprise.  Please help

Answer (score 0):

you need to do following things to add fee into paypal.

1. `app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\events.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
     <event name="payment_cart_collect_items_and_amounts">
      <observer name="vendor_extension_payment_collect_total" instance="Vendor\Extension\Observer\AddCustomAmountItem" />
   </event>
   </config>
   ```
2. `app\code\Vendor\Extension\Observer\AddCustomAmountItem.php`

   ```
   <?php
   namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;

   use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
   use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
   use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

   class AddCustomAmountItem implements ObserverInterface
   {
       public function execute(Observer $observer)
       {

           $cart = $observer->getEvent()->getCart();
           $customAmount = 100;
           $cart->addCustomItem(__('Custom Amount'), 1, -1.00 * $customAmount, 'customfee');
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I do not have app\code\Vendor\Extension\Observer\AddCustomAmountItem.php in my magento installation of 2.3.1.  I don't need a custom fee I just need to send the tax info.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: I will provide you way. And this is custom code that you need to do.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, can you help me setting custom tax_amount for quote item?